# Stringify and parse complex object with nested arrays from localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a very complex dictionary object consisting of very deeply nested combinations of objects and arrays.

I use a custom deepCopyObject function to make a deep copy of my object throughout my code. That works fine, I'm only including it because it's the only way I'm able to copy the object without a shallow reference.

The issue comes when I try to store and retrieve it from localStorage with parse and stringify. The below code returns:

nextQuestion local_user_dict is  [object Object]
test.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

The code below was structured by copying the object from the console in the browser and editing the keys/values. I left all of the structure intact including the "null" values which I didn't include but I assume is due to it being an array nested within the object.

I'm told that stringify and parse should work with deeply nested and complex objects including with arrays (Though I've read elsewhere online that's not true). How can I correctly pass this object and retrieve it from localStorage?

If I use my deep copy function on the object it works fine and displays as it should, the problem only occurs when stringifying and parsing from localStorage.

```
var test_dict = {
    "questions": {
        "obj1": {
            "words": [
                null,
                {
                    "test1": {
                        "test2": "test7",
                        "test3": "test6"
                    },
                    "test4": "test5"
                },
                {
                    "test8": {
                        "test9": 0,
                        "test10": "2",
                    },
                    "test11": [
                        null,
                        {
                            "test12": {
                                "no": 0,
                                "yes": 1
                            },
                            "test13": "test14"
                        },
                        {
                            "test15": {
                                "no": 0,
                                "yes": 1
                            },
                            "test16": "test17"
                        },
                        {
                            "test18": {
                                "no": 0,
                                "yes": 1
                            },
                            "test19": "test20"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

localStorage.setItem('user_dict', deepCopyObject(test_dict))
let local_user_dict = localStorage.getItem('user_dict')
console.log('nextQuestion local_user_dict is ', local_user_dict)
let parsed_local_user_dict = JSON.parse(local_user_dict)
console.log('nextQuestion parsed_local_user_dict is ', parsed_local_user_dict)
user_dict = deepCopyObject(parsed_local_user_dict)
console.log('nextQuestion user_dict is ', user_dict)

function deepCopyObject(inObject) {
    let outObject, value, key
    if (typeof inObject !== "object" || inObject === null) {
        return inObject
    }
    outObject = Array.isArray(inObject) ? [] : {}
    for (key in inObject) {
        value = inObject[key]
        outObject[key] = deepCopyObject(value)
    }
    return outObject
}
```

Comment: You need to `JSON.stringify()` your object not deep copy it. The only time stringify wouldnt work like expected is with non-regular objects, like say a DOM object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localstorage stores strings. not objects.

change

```
localStorage.setItem('user_dict', deepCopyObject(test_dict))
```

to

```
localStorage.setItem('user_dict', JSON.stringify(test_dict))
```

and ditch the copy.   you can actually use JSON parse and stringify to copy objects.